# how to increase the open file descriptor size in ubuntu

Tags: 18.04, files

i want to increase the open file descriptor size in linux current size is

```
ulimit -n
```

returns `1024`
i want to increase it to `65535` because my elasticsearch process needs it 
here is the link i am following 
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/setting-system-settings.html#limits.conf

i did added following line in `/etc/security/limits.conf`

```
*     soft   nofile  1024
*     hard   nofile  65535 
root     soft   nofile  1024
root     hard   nofile  65535
```

rebooted the system and `ulimit -n` still returning `1024`

another solution i added these lines in `/etc/security/limits.conf`

```
*    soft nofile 64000
*    hard nofile 64000
*        -  nproc   16384
root        -  nproc   16384
root soft nofile 64000
root hard nofile 64000
```

and 
`/etc/pam.d/common-session` needs to have this line in it:

```
session required pam_limits.so
```

and added following line in `/etc/pam.d/common-session-noninteractive` :

```
session required pam_limits.so
```

rebooted the system and it did not worked either 
followed this link as well 
https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19623-01/820-6168/file-descriptor-requirements.html
it gives error on the last command

```
 ulimit -n unlimited
bash: ulimit: open files: cannot modify limit: Operation not permitted
```

and

```
 sudo ulimit -n unlimited
sudo: ulimit: command not found
```

my elasticsearch process is giving me this error

```
[1]: max file descriptors [4096] for elasticsearch process is too low, increase to at least [65535]
```

any help would be appreciated